# Computing the marginal density

Tags: probability, random-variables

I was asked to compute the marginal density of $X$ for the pdf:
$$f(x, y) = \dfrac{6}{7}(x + y)^2,~ 0 ≤ x ≤ 1, ~0 ≤ y ≤ 1.$$

For this I got, $$\dfrac{6}{7}(x + 1/2)^2$$

Is this correct. If not where did I go wrong?

Comment: Is that $\int_0^1f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y  $? If so, you are correct.

Comment: Definitely no. Please show you integration to find where are you wrong.

Comment: I edited the information. I took the integral of the inside of the parentheses with respect to y. I just did not know what to do with the power, or if I should have expanded it and then take the integral with respect to y.

Comment: $$\int_0^1 \frac67(x+y)^2\,dy \neq  \frac67\left(x+\int_0^1 y\,dy\right)^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f_X(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dy = \frac{6}{7} \int_0^1 (x+y)^2 dy = \frac{2}{7} \left((x+1)^3 - x^3 \right)$$

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. Thank you!